# Converting String to int--java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString

Tags: java, string, parseint

Why would this not work and throw the following error?

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("A5"));
```

Error is:

```
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
        at DecisionTreeImpl.createTree(DecisionTreeImpl.java:321)
        at DecisionTreeImpl.<init>(DecisionTreeImpl.java:59)
```

Also if this is not a good method for converting the strings like "A5" to integer, what's the way to do it correctly in Java?

I am given a class (and I am supposed not to modify it at all) which is like this:

```
public class DecTreeNode {
    Integer label; //for 
    Integer attribute;
    Integer parentAttributeValue; // if is the root, set to "-1"
    boolean terminal;
    List<DecTreeNode> children;
```

So when I am instantiating this class all the values which I need to pass to it (including attributes and labels are all string) so I have no idea what I should do now that Integer.ParseInt is failing me!

It is given as a hint that you might want to inherit from DecTreeNode class but I was not sure if that is related at all! Any idea how to tackle this problem?

```
root= new DecTreeNode((trainingSet.labels.get(getMajority(instances, trainingSet.labels.size())),trainingSet.attributes.get(biggestEntropy), -1, TRUE);
```

Here's the error I receive :

```
The constructor DecTreeNode(String, String, int, boolean) is undefined
```

However the problem is I am not allowed to modify the class DecTreeNode to have a new constructor.

Here's the complete DecTreeNode that is supposed not to be modified:

```
/**
 * Possible class for internal organization of a decision tree.
 * Included to show standardized output method, print().
 * 
 * Do not modify. If you use,
 * create child class DecTreeNodeImpl that inherits the methods.
 * 
 */
public class DecTreeNode {
    Integer label; //for 
    Integer attribute;
    Integer parentAttributeValue; // if is the root, set to "-1"
    boolean terminal;
    List<DecTreeNode> children;

    DecTreeNode(Integer _label, Integer _attribute, Integer _parentAttributeValue, boolean _terminal) {
        label = _label;
        attribute = _attribute;
        parentAttributeValue = _parentAttributeValue;
        terminal = _terminal;
        if (_terminal) {
            children = null;
        } else {
            children = new ArrayList<DecTreeNode>();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add child to the node.
     * 
     * For printing to be consistent, children should be added
     * in order of the attribute values as specified in the
     * dataset.
     */
    public void addChild(DecTreeNode child) {
        if (children != null) {
            children.add(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's TrainingSet class:

```
public class DataSet {
    public List<String> labels = null;          // ordered list of class labels
    public List<String> attributes = null;      // ordered list of attributes
    public Map<String, List<String> > attributeValues = null; // map to ordered discrete values taken by attributes 
    public List<Instance> instances = null; // ordered list of instances
    private final String DELIMITER = ",";   // Used to split input strings
```

Comment: Because A5 is not a valid int?

Comment: As in you want it to be interpreted as hex?

Comment: So how would you tackle it?

Comment: @FatalError oh no...it's just a feature name/labeling thing in decision tree.

Comment: @Mona Jalal you cannot turn a non int to an int. Remove the A before the 5 lol :)

Comment: is it a case where only the first character of the string is an alphabet? like always?

Comment: Your question seems like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Would you mind sharing with us more context like where does this string come from, why you want to convert it to integer (how are you going to use it)?

Comment: @Pshemo you are right, I added the problem detail I was facing. Please take a look at the update.

Comment: @Mona Jalal what's the class constructor? as I don't see String reference variables there.

Comment: @Alboz I edited the question now and added the complete DecTreeNode. Please note that this class is supposed not to be modified!

Comment: @Mona Jalal as suspected the constructor accepts only Integers. Why are you trying to pass Strings to it?? Show my how YOU are calling the constructor?

Comment: @Alboz did you read the complete question? I have written how I am calling the constructor: `root= new DecTreeNode((trainingSet.labels.get(getMajority(instances, trainingSet.labels.size())),trainingSet.attributes.get(biggestEntropy), -1, TRUE);` also traingSet is another non-modifiable class and the item it returns are all string

Comment: @Mona Jalal and I'm telling you that the constructor that you are calling doesn't exist. Java is also telling you The constructor DecTreeNode(String, String, int, boolean) is undefined. You have to call the constructor passing Integers and one boolean at the end. We cannot know what are: trainingSet.labels.get(getMajority(instances, trainingSet.labels.size())),trainingSet.attributes.get(biggestEntropy)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62441/discussion-between-mona-jalal-and-alboz).

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you "The constructor DecTreeNode(String, String, int, boolean) is undefined" because your class DecTreeNode does not define a constructor with those data types. You can create a class DecTreeNodeImpl extending DecTreeNode(as the comments on the DecTreeNode class suggests) and implement all the methods/constructors that need parameters of type String.

Answer (score 0):

If label is always one char, then solution is simple:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("A5".substring(1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know how many letters there are (1 or more), I would personally go for something like this that removes all non-digits:

```
String labeledNumber="A5"

String str = labeledNumber.replaceAll("\\D+","");

System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str));
```

This would work also with labels like: "abc12" "a-1232" etc.

Comment: This is not correct answer. I mentioned in various comments that input string can be anything. Not just hex.

Comment: @Mona Jalal first try it and then judge. It's  not hex! hex it's just a variable name. This will remove all the non numeric part of the string and keep the numbers!

Comment: I changed the variable name :P

Comment: @MonaJalal that's a big change, I'll give it a look :). Anyway this addresses what you asked at the beginning..

Comment: What you have written above, I believe doesn't differentiate between B5 and A5 per se! Right?